# By mistake i deleted google play service from android sdk manager how can i install back.becasue that folder itself not appearing

Tags: android, performance

I am new to android while working with google map By mistake i deleted Google play service from android SDK manager how can i install back and i also don't want to update my SDK manager 
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this package from Android SDK Manager and install it again.

or add to gradle:

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
```

}

Comment: how to install again? there is no such folder appear named as google play services

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it again, if your using eclipse goto windows-->SDK manager-Extras-->google play services.

Answer (score 0):

When i update my window manager then Google play services became visible.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Android SDK Manager and make sure you have the latest version of Google Play Services downloaded and installed. Once this is complete, upon up your build.gradle file and add:

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89')
}
```